# Can NIFI storage be extended?

Tags: apache-nifi

I have 2 Sites (FE & BE )that on each I need to install the NIFI Cluster. FE site is required to transfer data to the BE site using site-to-site protocol.

I do know that from time to I have connectivity issues between the sites. since I don't want to lose data, is it possible to configure the FE NIFI cluster to Keep data for 2-3 days in case of a network disconnection between the sites? I do know it will require more disk space

If it is possible, which repository I need to extend the Content or the Flow file? and how can it be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the destination cluster becomes unavailable and causes back-pressure (queues filling up) in the source cluster, you can increase the total available size of a Queue to increase how much back-pressure it keeps. Right click -> Configuration on the Queue you want to increase, and adjust the 'Back Pressure...Threshold' (you can adjust # of FFs and size in GB). Your FF Content Repository needs to have enough disk space to accomodate what you configure.

If it's not causing back pressure in the previous queue, you could branch off the Failure relationship and choose how you handle it - you could write to disk and re-ingest, or you could make a retry loop and increase the back-pressure here.